# How to search product data by id and name in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a index named product in `elastic-search` with field id, name etc..
I want to search products by id or name but my id field is integer and name is a text, I tried following but getting error while searching by name.

> error type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string:
>   \"test\""

```
  def self.search_by_name_or_id(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search({
      query: {
        bool: {
          must:{
            multi_match: {
              query: query,
              fields: ["id", "name"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  end
```

Comment: can you please comment if my answer solves your problem or you have any further question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Exception is clear, that you are trying to search `test` which is a String in the integer field and elasticsearch is not able to convert `test` in integer, instead of `test` if you had search for `10` or `100`, then elasticsearch would convert it into integer and would not throw the exception.

**Solution**
You are trying to mix 2 things here, I am not sure about your design but if your id field can contain pure numbers i.e. integers, then it's not possible to achieve in a single query the way you are doing.

If you can convert your id field to String, then `multi_match` query would work perfectly fine, otherwise, you need to first check in your application, that search term can be converted to number or not, i.e. `10` or `100` would work fine but `test10` or `test100` would not and anyway there is no point of searching these terms in `id` field as it won't be present as its defined as integer in ES and ES would reject documents containing these terms during indexing time only. **So based on your application code check you can construct the ES query which may or may not include the `id` field in `multi-match`.**